# Backbone Marionette Target Element in el with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on creating a basic question app to better understand backbone marionette. I'm my free-text questions right now use the same `"#question-number-range` id for setting the range of numbers users can enter when taking a survey. Then I split up the range and assign the min/max values accordingly.

This works great for the first free-text question view. But when I try to do the same thing on a second it ends up getting set to the first's min/max values because they have the same id.

What I'm wondering - is there a way I can do something like `$(@el < '#question-number-range')` to target just the input within the current view's el, rather than any input that has that id?

Or am I completely going about this wrong and need to maybe dynamically create the ids?

Comment: If you have duplicate `id` attributes then you don't have valid HTML and all sorts of unexpected things can happen. Use a class instead and then you should be able to `@$('.whatever-the-class-is')` to find the element.

Comment: That was perfectly right. If you want to throw that in as an answer I'll give you credit! ;)

Comment: So basically just for my understanding. As long as I do the @$ it'll get me the element with that class within this view?

Comment: I included some notes on what `@$()` does below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) is:

> A unique identifier for the element.
>
> There **must** not be multiple elements in a document that have the same `id` value.

so if you have duplicate `id`s then you don't really have (valid) HTML and all sorts of strange things can happen.

A better approach is to use a `class` to identify elements of interest. Then you could use [`@$('.whatever-the-class-is')`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) to find the element within your view's `el`:

> **$ (jQuery)** `view.$(selector)`
>
> If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a **$** function that runs queries scoped within the view's element. If you use this scoped jQuery function, you don't have to use model ids as part of your query to pull out specific elements in a list, and can rely much more on HTML class attributes. It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`

so `@$(x)` is the same as `@el.find(x)` and will limit your search to the view.